# A function that knows the name of the package from which it's been called

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two packages:

- `my_tools`, a series tools including function `f()`
- `my_project` which has `my_tools` as a dependency and which is using its `f()` function

My problem is that when I call `f()` from `my_project` package's code, I need `f()` to be able to find it's been called from the `my_project` package (and for instance return the package's name).

For example:

```
# my_project/code.py
from my_tools import f
print f()  # prints 'my_project'
```

I've been playing around with `sys` and `inspect` but couldn't find any solution so far.

Comment: `def f(): return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals.get('__package__', '?')`

Comment: Returns `my_tools`, not `my_project` ;)

Comment: I've got `my_project`. Check [`__package__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__)

Comment: Or see https://asciinema.org/a/atjvs4v32spu8tzt9i48piagm

Comment: I think there's a difference in this asciinema snippet: `my_tools.py` isn't part of a `my_tools` python package installed as a dependency of `my_project`.  I guess this is (part of) the reason why I don't get the same result...

Comment: I also tried that case, got `my_project`. (BTW, I used `from my_project.my_tools import f` to make it work both in Python 2/3)

Comment: I suspect you import the `code` directly, not as submodule of `my_project`. Could you check that?

Comment: I tried to properly explain what I'm doing here (great tool btw, thanks): https://asciinema.org/a/e8gfeu34h0n4loz3n5ut2o4q6

Answer (score 2):

Use [`inspect.currentframe`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) to get frame information, then check `__package__` attribute of the module:

```
import inspect

def f():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    return frame.f_back.f_globals.get('__package__')
```